Django_ CreateView class showing class availability
I have a Gym Project in django, with booking_create (CreateView) to create bookings for a gym class. I am using a Model and Form, with user and class types. The HTML template has a Form for class booking. I want to make this Form unavailable when the class is full booked, showing instead a warning message.
My thoughts:
I should have a booking count for created bookings (e.g., booking_count), rest this value to the class capacity and save this in a variable (like, av_places= class_capacity-booking_count) and if  av_places is greater than zero, show the Form for registration, otherwise show a warning message.
Not sure how to add this functionality to the class view
Below are the class model, view and template.
models.py:

class Class_Book (models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    class = models.ForeignKey(Class, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default= '')
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.class}'

views.py

class booking_create (LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    form_class= Booking_Form 
    template_name= ‘booking_create.html'
    success_url=reverse_lazy('home')

template:

 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {% csrf_token %}

     {{ form.as_p }}
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">SAVE</button>
  </form>


What is your question then? You've just described what you want to do and what approach you've thought for it but haven't really asked any question... Also that class = ... will throw a SyntaxError.

Does each Class has max number of users to attend?Or is the max booking associated with the gym itself?

What you want to do is make sure that if a class is fully booked, people won’t be able to see the booking form. Instead, they’ll see a message letting them know that the class is full. This can be done by adding some logic to your view.
First, Let's Tweak the Models
Your Booking model looks good, but just a quick note:
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Booking(models.Model):
    # It's fine to allow null=True, but usually, you’d want every booking to be tied to a user. 
    # You can automatically set the user in the view, so you might
    # not need null=True unless there's a specific reason.
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True
    )
    klass = models.ForeignKey(Class, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Just a heads up that default="" isn’t valid for ForeignKey fields, so it’s best to remove that.

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.klass}"

Adding the Booking Logic in the View
Now, let's add the logic to your view to check if a class is full. We’ll override the get method in your BookingCreateView to do this:
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class BookingCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = BookingForm
    template_name = "booking_create.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("home")

    # Override the get method to check for availability
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs) -> HttpResponse:
        klass_id = self.kwargs.get('klass_id')
        klass = Class.objects.get(id=klass_id)
        
        # Count how many bookings already exist for this class
        booking_count = Booking.objects.filter(klass=klass).count()
        
        # Check if the class is full
        if booking_count >= klass.capacity:  # Assuming 'capacity' is a field in your Class model
            return redirect(reverse("booking_closed"))  # Redirect to a 'booking closed' page
        
        # If there's space, show the form
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def form_valid(self, form: BookingForm):
        # Inject the user to the form before saving.
        booking: Booking = form.instance
        booking.user = self.request.user        
        response = super().form_valid(form)#form save happens here
        return response


You’ll want to create a simple page that tells users the class is fully booked. Here’s how you can do it with either a class-based view (CBV) or a function-based view (FBV).
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class BookingClosedView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "booking_closed.html"

Using a Function-Based View (FBV):
from django.shortcuts import render

def booking_closed_view(request):
    return render(request, "booking_closed.html")


Don’t forget to add the URL pattern for this in your urls.py:

Yo welcome@maria. Consider marking the answer accepted if it helped you
